# Excel and Word want to connect to arc.msn.com

Tags: windows-7, proxy, microsoft-excel-2016, microsoft-word-2016

When one of my users opens Excel or Word, a popup opens up asking his credentials for our proxy server. Apparently, Excel and/or Word try to connect to arc.msn.com (for whatever reason).

He is using Office 2016 on Windows 7, and he is the only one who experiences this issue. All other users who are using Office 2016 on Windows 7 do not get this popup, nor are they allowed to access said website.

What causes Excel and/or Word to connect to this website? And how do we turn it off?

Thanks!